# IE Web Controls: Let IE10+ act as non-compliant browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, web-controls, legacy

I have some ASP.NET legacy code using the IE Web Controls for early ASP.NET functions. We've kept it alive for some time but with IE10 it stopped working. In non-IE browsers, however, the controls revert to a less dynamic but working version. I was wondering if there is a way to simply tell the controls to default to that state for modern IEs, instead of trying to do something smart and fail?

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/p/x-ua-compatible-meta-tag.htm

Comment: sounds nice but doesn't help

Comment: then your script is sniffing IE in a way it shouldn't because with the meta IE10 should act like the older IE versions that do work; or without anything, IE detection in IE10 should fail, thus invoking the standard working version...

Comment: Can u show a snipped of the page with relevant code/markup? Also, what version of ASP.NET/.NET framework are u running this on?